# Regression models not passing

Tags: regression, predictive-models

I've implemented an optimization algorithm to optimize the revenue of a particular store. I've done this for my 2020-2022 data. Moving forward, what I aim to do is to predict the difference (% increase or decrease) between my normal revenue and optimized revenue.

I've done linear regression, GLM, GAM, and regression trees to try and predict this value but for my linear models I keep failing the assumptions (normality, independence, etc.) and for GAM and Regression trees, I keep getting high scores for RMSE and MAPE.

My data has a few outliers but I think these are necessary to be kept since there are days when some factors (like prices) are too high/low. I've also tried the models with different data transformations (log, sqrt) and did some parameter tuning where necessary.

---

Answering the comments:
-For the linear regression model and GLM: I am failing the Shapiro-Wilk test and DurbinWatson and Breusch Pagan tests (normality, independence, and homoscedasticity tests). All p-values are always less than 0.5. When I do the data transformations, when I pass the SW test, I'll fail the other two or v/v.

-My most basic model has a fairly good performance. With a relatively high R^2 and both predictors are considered as significant.
[image: Model summary]

-Here are some plots as well:
[image: Relationship of optimized revenue with normal_solar (one of my predictors]

[image: Relationship of optimized_revenue with avg_price (my other predictor)]

[image: Model residuals]

[image: Fitted values vs residuals]

Comment: Greetings and welcome to CV! It may help if you provide some plots of the data to see what exactly is contributing to different issues with your regression fits, if there are indeed problems to find.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What normality and independence assumptions do you violate for the linear regression? There are a lot of misconceptions about what is assumed to be normal and independent. Even if you do violate standard assumptions, how does it affect your performance? If you get a model that, despite (perhaps slight) violations of some assumptions, winds up making accurate predictions that can inform good decision-making, do you even have a reason to care about the assumption violations?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comments. I've added the plots as mentioned by @ShawnHemelstrand.

Comment: Also, @Dave, I've tested the normality and independence on the whole model. May I ask what you meant by _"If you get a model that, despite (perhaps slight) violations of some assumptions, winds up making accurate predictions that can inform good decision-making, do you even have a reason to care about the assumption violations?"_ Sorry, my understanding is that assumptions must be met for us to justify our use of the mode. Thank you again for your time!

Comment: In your last plot, please put residuals on the y-axis and fitted values on the x-axis, as is the usual convention (and with good reason in this case). It will be much easier on people responding to your question if you have them the conventional way around (and something of the nature of the lack of fit of the model will then be clearer)

Comment: @lyramay Normality and independence of what? There are tests that you can run (and people often, mistakenly, run) that are unrelated to the true assumptions of models. $//$ Many models are fairly robust to modest or even quite substantial violations of classical assumptions. If your main goal is to predict, the main assumption, I would argue, is that you have a model that can reliably predict, and if you can demonstrate this, producing that model qualifies as useful work. You wouldn't avoid using a model that would make you a billionaire because of a statistics technicality, would you?